# Customizing Python unidecode module

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

Unidecode is a wonderful tool, but I'd like to change processing of several cyrillic letters. For example, I prefer to have a letter 'я' replaced with 'ya', not 'ia'. What file should I modify? There are lots of files named like 'x00a.py', unfortunately I can't find the one that contains needed symbols (small 'я' is 'x44F', for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each filename is a 3-digit prefix of a 5-digit value, so you’re looking for x004.py. Specifically [line 81](https://github.com/avian2/unidecode/blob/578cdb9eba3eeaed80871dca103fd156de07e5b5/unidecode/x004.py#L81):

```
'ia', # 0x4f
```